# git log difference between 2 branches AND starting from a specific commit id

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, git-log

I'm doing `git log HEAD..remotes/upstream/master` to get the difference in commits between the two branches. I want to do the same thing but listing commits after a specific commit hash.

For example, my current output is something like:

```
1e191 commit 5
e0fa4 commit 4
fc27c commit 3
99df2 commit 2
9cfef commit 1
```

I would like to pass in `9cfef` and get:

```
1e191 commit 5
e0fa4 commit 4
fc27c commit 3
99df2 commit 2
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: In the `x..y` notation, the `y` part is "what to include" and the `x` part is "what to exclude".  `HEAD..upstream/master` excludes `HEAD`-and-back.  `9cfef` is "one past" `HEAD`, so `9cfef..remotes/upstream/master` excludes `9cfef`, `HEAD`, and so on backwards.  In other words just start the `..` expression with the exclude-point.

Comment: @torek i tried that but then ran into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225832/git-log-revision-range-gives-incorrect-range-of-commits) issue. in any case, what if in your example, if `9cfef` is not "one past" HEAD. If there are other commits in between, I would like to capture them too.

Comment: That kind of behavior occurs when the commit graph is more complicated, because `x..y` is really `y ^x` and `y` selects `y`-and-all-its-ancestors while `^x` deselects `x`-and-its-ancestors.  I can't draw this properly in a comment though.