# git log revision range gives incorrect range of commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, dvcs, git-log

I am trying to use list all commits within a given range on a branch using the  argument of `git log`. For some reason it doesn't seem to be giving me the right result (or maybe I'm understanding the command wrong?).

Here's the steps for what I'm doing:

1. Clone the repo

   `git clone https://github.com/openstack/nova.git`
2. Do `git log` and these are the last 9 commits:

   ```
   d5bde44 Merge "Make metadata password routines use Instance object"
   6cbc9ee Merge "Fix object change detection"
   39b7875 Merge "Fix object leak in nova.tests.objects.test_fields.TestObject"
   94d1034 Merge "maint: correct docstring parameter description"
   6407f17 Merge "Fix live_migration method's docstring"
   7406661 Merge "Fix infinitely reschedule instance due to miss retry info"
   9d8a34f Merge "Remove unused code from test_compute_cells"
   429cd4b Fix object change detection
   01381b8 Fix object leak in nova.tests.objects.test_fields.TestObject
   ...
   ```
3. Lets say I want to get all the commits starting after `01381b8`. I issue `git log 01381b8..HEAD` and the following output is seen:

   ```
   d5bde44 Merge "Make metadata password routines use Instance object"
   6cbc9ee Merge "Fix object change detection"
   39b7875 Merge "Fix object leak in nova.tests.objects.test_fields.TestObject"
   94d1034 Merge "maint: correct docstring parameter description"
   6407f17 Merge "Fix live_migration method's docstring"
   7406661 Merge "Fix infinitely reschedule instance due to miss retry info"
   9d8a34f Merge "Remove unused code from test_compute_cells"
   429cd4b Fix object change detection
   2214bc0 Remove unused code from test_compute_cells
   9639b55 Fix infinitely reschedule instance due to miss retry info
   a5184d3 Fix live_migration method's docstring
   76729a3 maint: correct docstring parameter description
   28224a6 Make metadata password routines use Instance object
   ```

Wow! I actually got **13** commits in that output when I expected **8**. What is going on here? Is the revision range the correct mechanism to get show commits after a given commit? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Probably not a bug. What kind of output do you get when you do `git log --oneline --graph`, with and without the revision range?

Answer (score 9):

The problem here lies with the slippery notion of "after".

Commits are not so much "before" and "after" as they are "embedded in a graph".  In this case, since the repository is clone-able, I cloned it.  Apparently it's fairly active:

```
$ git log --oneline -9
77bad25 Merge "Remove deprecated config option names: Juno Edition"
d4d712a Merge "Deprecate instance_get_by_uuid() from conductor"
d5bde44 Merge "Make metadata password routines use Instance object"
6cbc9ee Merge "Fix object change detection"
39b7875 Merge "Fix object leak in nova.tests.objects.test_fields.TestObject"
94d1034 Merge "maint: correct docstring parameter description"
6407f17 Merge "Fix live_migration method's docstring"
7406661 Merge "Fix infinitely reschedule instance due to miss retry info"
9d8a34f Merge "Remove unused code from test_compute_cells"
```

This is newer than your last-9 output.  More interesting, though, is how these look if they are logged with `--graph` added (and I'll bump the number to 10):

```
$ git log --oneline --graph -n 10

*   77bad25 Merge "Remove deprecated config option names: Juno Edition"
|\  
| * d0a02fa Remove deprecated config option names: Juno Edition
* |   d4d712a Merge "Deprecate instance_get_by_uuid() from conductor"
|\ \  
| * | 1d340cc Deprecate instance_get_by_uuid() from conductor
* | |   d5bde44 Merge "Make metadata password routines use Instance object"
|\ \ \  
| |/ /  
| * | 28224a6 Make metadata password routines use Instance object
* | |   6cbc9ee Merge "Fix object change detection"
|\ \ \  
| * | | 429cd4b Fix object change detection
* | | |   39b7875 Merge "Fix object leak in nova.tests.objects.test_fields.TestO
|\ \ \ \  
| |/ / /  
| * | | 01381b8 Fix object leak in nova.tests.objects.test_fields.TestObject
```

(we get a different set of "topmost" commits because `--graph` modifies the traversal, which is why I went to 10 commits).

To understand what's going on here, you need to look beyond `git log` to `git rev-list`.  Like many git commands, `git log` *uses* `git rev-list` to pick revisions to display.  (Some git commands literally run `git rev-list` while others share its source code, but either way it works out the same.)

The git revision notation `x..y` is shorthand for `^x y` (or `y ^x`—these mean the same thing).  Whether you write a name like `master` or `origin/stable/havana`, or an indirect name like `HEAD`, or a raw commit-ID, or a shortened raw commit-ID like `77bad25`, the `x` and `y` parts are resolved to the underlying git object (which in our case should be a commit).  You can observe the resolving step by using `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse master
77bad252096f7a4a8174340f0f2a3baf1fd52195
$ git rev-parse HEAD
77bad252096f7a4a8174340f0f2a3baf1fd52195
$ git rev-parse origin/stable/havana
0bf0bb4b5df64f7266c903a986d0b90a1f223822
```

What `git rev-list` does with this is to work backwards from this commit to find its parent commit(s), and then from those commits to their parents, and so on.  The result is an ancestor-set.

The ancestors of `master` are, at this point, in no particular order:

- `master` itself: `77bad25...`
- `master`'s first parent, `git rev-parse master^1`: `d4d712a...`
- `master`'s second parent, `git rev-parse master^2`: `d0a02fa...`
- `master`'s first parent's first parent, `git rev-parse master^1^1`: `d5bde44...`
- `master`'s first parent's second parent, `git rev-parse master^1^2`: `1d340cc...`

and of course many more, going back for many commits:

```
$ git rev-list master | wc -l
   27918
```

So `git rev-list master` selects all 27-thousand-and-some commits, and `git log master` would show you all of them (in some order, with the order modified based on additional options passed to `git rev-list` via `git log`).

To exclude some of those, you can tell `git rev-list` to start with some particular revision—such as `01381b8`—and find all of its ancestors (including `01381b8` itself):

```
$ git rev-list 01381b8 | wc -l
   27901
```

At this point, this is 17 fewer commits than are found by starting at `master` and working backwards (and there are no commits in this second list that are not already in that first one).  So if you tell `git rev-list` to give you "all commits starting from `master`, minus all commits starting from `01381b8`", you should get 17 commits:

```
$ git rev-list master ^01381b8 | wc -l
      17
```

and indeed that's what we see.  (The actual list is not all that interesting, but you can see it with `git rev-list master ^01381b8`, or equivalently, `git rev-list 01381b8..master`.)

These commits are the ones `git log` will show you, given the same revision range.

You can spend days studying the `git rev-list` documentation and still miss items (for instance, `--graph` tells you that it "enables parent rewriting" and "implies `--topo-order`" and until I checked just now, I had forgotten about the parent rewriting part.  Fortunately that does not apply here anyway, just the need for `--date-order` to force the graphed version to sort by date rather than topologically.)

Answer (score -2):

Use this below command,

> git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cblue%h%Creset -%C(red)%d%Creset %s
>   %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit

It will give you log of commits in one line with branch name, author details, graph, date in a colourful way.

Try this !! its really amazing.

Comment: may i know the reason of giving -1 :(

Comment: Not my downvote, but perhaps your answer got downvoted because it does not really answer the question and is rather a comment to toreks post.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: thanks for the update!! As per my understanding towards this question, getting the log properly is the main intention of this question. And my answer will really add to the intention of question.

Comment: @trinth: i hope i am fullfiling your main intention of your question.